# How to make feet act as lower position limit for IK rigs

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I wanted to be able to move the hips of a character with it's feet staying at floor level, so I've created IK bones and added constraints. It works; but then, the feet snap to the IK bone's position:

[image]

I only need something like "ground limit", to tell both feet to not sink under floor level (for example, when you move hips bone) - and I want to be able to control feet bones independently, so for example: 
"Ground limit" bones will *always* stay at the same floor position. When I move the foot bone, it will move independently (to be able to raise feet in air), but when I move the hips bone, the feet will be limited to *not* go under the floor level. The only thing I need is to be able to use IK so when I move the hips downwards, the legs will bend and when I move the foot, the leg will bend - but to prevent foot bones snapping into foot IK bones position.**

I almost did what I wanted, but still something is wrong, i've created extra hips-to-legs bones to connect legs to hips, this way it works like i want with Auto IK, but when i move one foot, hips are rotating which causes sinking another foot into ground. Here is my .blend file with this setup: pasteall.org/blend/36087 – Any ideas? :(

**Update:** I will precise the problem even more clearly: How to prevent a bone with IK modifier from snapping into Target object position?

Comment: I think you need Floor constraint

Comment: Thanks, i've just tried it, but it works only when my bones are not connected. When i connect my bones in edit mode (to be able to use AutoIK and e.g. moving feet will move whole leg) feet does not respect this constraint anymore. I want to make it like that: When i move hips downwards, legs will bend when feet will reach floor level, which will cause crouch position.

Comment: Ik constraint overrides all constraints in the ik chain, you want to put the floor constraint on the ik-target bone, the floor constraint should target the characters root bone.

Comment: Hmm i did it and the foot bone snaps to root bone when doing that... Here is my .blend file, could you please tell me if there is something wrong with my setup and why it's not working? http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36070

Comment: I've tried again, but i still can't manage that. The only thing i need is to be able to use IK (1. So when i move hips downwards, legs will bend 2. So when i move foot, leg will bend) - but to prevent foot bones snapping into foot IK bones position.

Comment: I almost did it but still something is wrong, i've created extra hips-to-legs bones to connect legs to hips, this way it works like i want with Auto IK, but when i move one foot, hips are rotating which causes sinking another foot into ground. Here is my .blend file with this setup: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36087