# Why I can't keyframe position of hips bone?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes

When i move hips bone and keyframe it, its position does not interpolate, but it stays in the same position. However, rotation on leg bones (caused by IK chain when moving hips) is keyframing properly.
Here is my .blend file: [BLEND FILE](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36121)

I've set the keyset to LocRot, so it should be ok. Any ideas?

( The problem came up from troubleshooting [THIS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30871/how-to-make-feet-act-as-lower-position-limit-for-ik-rigs) one )

Comment: Please clarify your question with one or two screen images.  It helps others to get a bare minimum of understanding.

Comment: Have the same problem, try Visual Rotation. All your bones in the armature have to be parented, otherwise bonse without high parent cant be visual loc or rot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place two keyframes on different frames for interpolation.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that it already had a keyframes, but only for rotation - that's why it was not interpolating position values. I've set position keyframes at the beginning, and not it works. Thanks